# Error Reading Variable, Cannot Access Memory

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I tried to solve my problem with a precedent topic but couldn't apply to my situation, here is a code for finding the maximum of an array recursively in an array in c. The debug gives the error

> > Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> >     0x0000000000400682 in maxarray (arr=0x7fffffffeb30, n=10, i=0,
> >         maximum=) at main.c:23

There is an adress for maximum and I don't understand why it can't access to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxarray ( int arr[], int n , int i, int maximum);

int main(void){
    int arr[10];
    int maximum = 0;
    puts("the array is");
    for (size_t i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    arr[i]=(rand()%10);
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("the maximum is %d",  maxarray(arr,10,0,maximum));
    return 0;
}

int maxarray (int arr[10], int n, int i, int maximum){
    if (i<10){
        if (maximum<arr[i]){
            maximum=arr[i];
        }
        maxarray(arr, n, i++, maximum);
        }
    else{
    return maximum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `i++` returns the value of `i` and *then* increments it.

`maxarray(arr, n, i++, maximum)` keeps calling itself with `i = 0` and you eventually run out of call stack memory.

You could simply use `i + 1` since there is no reason to modify `i` in this scope, or use `++i`.

Also you simply ignore the return value of the recursion calls, this recursion, even if it was working, is accomplishing nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I've kept your program virtually the same; just re-jigged `maxarray` not to be recursive.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxarray (int arr[], int size, int maximum);

int main(void){
    int arr[10];
    int maximum = 0;
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    printf("the array is: ");
    for (size_t i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        arr[i]=(rand()%10);
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("the maximum is %d", maxarray(arr, size, maximum));
    return 0;
}

int maxarray (int arr[], int size, int maximum){
    printf("sizeof(arr) is: %lld \n", size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      if (maximum<arr[i]){
          maximum=arr[i];
      }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

Output:

```
the array is: 3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
sizeof(arr) is: 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
the maximum is 9
```